# Hibernate error after migrating from spring-boot 2.0.0 to spring-boot 2.1.1

Tags: java, spring-boot

After I changed Spring boot configuration from 2.0.0.RELEASE to 2.1.1.RELEASE. I cannot build my project
It could not import `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` class

[SessionFactory not resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ablg.png)

Thanks,
Lam

This is my pom and it works ok with spring-boot **2.0.0.RELEASE**

```
<groupId>com.vas</groupId>
<artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>YYY</name>
<description>AAAA</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ucanaccess/ucanaccess -->
    <!--dependency> <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId> <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.4</version> </dependency -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons Email validator,... -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
        <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also changed org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api to javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api but it not work.

Thanks.

Sorry, I am newbie to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.SessionFactory` is included in `hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final`, which is included in spring data jpa of spring boot **2.1.1.RELEASE**. You need to import the dependency correctly.